# How to declare a new object type in typescript

Tags: typescript

When the type is declared as in the code block below

When declaring a new type C is an object, the key value is the key value of A, and the type of each key is B.

How to declare C with only A and B..?

```
type A = {
 home: string
 info:string
 about:string
}
type B = "open" | "close"
```

desired result

```
type C = {
 home: "open" | "close"
 info:"open" | "close"
 about:"open" | "close"
}
```

Comment: Why do you even need type A and B?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `in` like this:

```
type C = { [K in keyof A]: B };
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) type:

```
type C = Record<keyof A, B>
```